# Not sure how to check for group properties on this problem

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Show that the matrix $ A_\alpha= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ 
\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha 
\end{bmatrix} 
,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ forms a group under matrix multiplication.

I'm not sure what this problem is asking me to do. I mean I understand that I have to show that a group is formed under multiplication, but how exactly do I show that if there is no set of elements being given? How would I go about, say, checking if the first property holds if there is no set of elements being given?

Comment: You have an infinite number of elements, one for each $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. So forst you need to show that $A_\alpha A_\beta=A_\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is some function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: Find an identity element.Show that associativity holds $A_a (A_b A_c) = (A_a A_b) A_c$, and show that there is an inverse element.

Comment: @Andrei I see. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrei I need clarification on one more thing. How do I start checking for the first property. I was thinking of doing $(\forall \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}) A_\alphaA_\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ ... but in this case $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do not represent the matrices, they are only the arguments of $A$. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: You are correct. Let's call $R$ the set of all matrices $A_\alpha$ of the form described in the problem. Then you need to show that $\forall A_x,A_y\in R$ you get $A_xA_y\in R$. You can use $X=A_x$ and $Y=A_y$, and you need to show $\forall X,Y \in R$ you get $XY\in R$. Note that $R$ is the set of rotation matrices, and not $\mathbb R$, the set of real numbers

Comment: Also search the web for $R=SO(2)$. The determinant of these orthogonal matrices is equal to $1$. So your set of matrices forms a famous group.

Comment: I suspect that something called *a subgroup criterion* has been introduced in your class already. And also the fact that the invertible 2x2-matrices form a group. Show that this collection is a subgroup of the latter. Forget the axioms, they are tedious to check. For example associativity holds for all matrices (by linear algebra), and comes free of charge.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for the three properties of group, but before you do that, take into account what those matrices mean (rotations by an angle of $\alpha$). Your elements are those matrices (there are uncountably many elements, one for each $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)$

Now, check the first property (the existence of an identity). Rotation by an angle of $0$ probably works as it means leaving an object the same.

The next property is that if you take any two elements and multiply them together then they end up in the same set (the binary operation is in fact closed). Take a rotation of $\alpha$, another of $\beta$. And do the multiplication. As you can probably guess, it is a rotation by an angle of $\alpha+\beta$, but do the math.

Then, you need to check the property of existence of an inverse element. Take any matrix $M_\alpha$ and see if you can find an element that reverses that operation (probably -wink, wink- rotating the other way works $-\alpha$)

Lastly, show there is associativity (this requires you to do none other than the math).

Answer (score 1):

You know that the matrix product is associative. So, that's one thing that you don't have to check.

And you know that the identity matrix times any other matrix is that matrix. But $A_0=\operatorname{Id}_2$, and therefore your set of matrices has an identity element.

Finally, if $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, then\begin{align}A_\alpha^{\,-1}&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\alpha)&-\sin(\alpha)\\\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\alpha)&\sin(\alpha)\\-\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(-\alpha)&-\sin(-\alpha)\\\sin(-\alpha)&\cos(-\alpha)\end{bmatrix}\\&=A_{-\alpha}.\end{align}

Comment: How did you get $\sin (-\alpha)$ on the third row upper right corner of the matrix?

Comment: It was a typo. I meant $-\sin(-\alpha)$.